# Angular material autocomplete add new value as object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms

I am using angular material 2 autocomplete. As we know user can search a value and if that value exists in the list it will have that value stored as object as my array consists of array of objects let's say id and name.

**Problem:** Is it possible to alter the new value that does not exit in my list so that whenever i do a post with my FormGroup's with all the other values to back-end it's always an object with id which would be null and name as the value that user has inputted for that form control.

Let me know if you no get i will try to explain more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you'd have a server with an endpoint to add an autocomplete value and one to get all of them, then in the component ngOnInt you get the autocomplete values and in the onSubmit you'd add code to post the input's value? Is the null id the problem?

Comment: yea you are right that i can alter the value before posting to server but the thing is i was looking to alter the fb.group({ name: 'someName', add: 'some address', autoCompleteSomething: ''  <-- this value}). autoCompleteSomething can be string if user does not select from the existing values or object if user does. Or am i thinking wrong should prefer something else ?

Comment: It should be a string in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add the `ID` or a unique value that can represents that object then using the `ID` you can simply know which object been selected.